# null pointer exception reading properties file

Tags: java, netbeans

I really don't know what else to do. I normally put my properties files in my source folder (I use Netbeans, by the way) and when I read it, everything works fine.

Today, I created a new properties file in the source folder and tried to read it and I kept getting a null pointer exception, connoting the nonexistence of the file in the source folder. Yet, there was another properties file in said source folder and I was able to read that one fine. I deleted both properties files and started afresh, but this time I can't seem to read anything.

My codes are fine:

```
Properties pp = new Properties();                
pp.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/errors.properties"));
```

Then I did the clean and build for my project, and now one of the classes can read the errors.properties file (same code, nothing changed), but I'm also now getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for my second class when I try running it.

WTH!?

Comment: Are your properties files being copied to `build/classes` or `target`, wherever your .class files are located?

Comment: i don't have any problem with netbeans 7.2. getting NoClassDefFoundError means you are missing a library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Properties pp = new Properties();
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("errors.properties");
pp.load(is);
```

Btw. this is **not** a bug in NetBeans.

If you use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("errors.properties")` your `error.properties` has to be where you class is.

*Note: i used `InputStream is` only because otherwise the line gets too long. Of course you can put both lines into one.*

Comment: `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` first attempts to do `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`. If that fails, then it will try getting `ClassLoader` from `ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader()`. That's the only difference.